# How to print the treebank of text file

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, evaluation

I am working with StanfordCoreNLP and I want to evaluate the results for my real time dataset which is in normal text file [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iiyb4vS4LLcL0UOagCiKwtQLfHgZZXog/view?usp=drives](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iiyb4vS4LLcL0UOagCiKwtQLfHgZZXog/view?usp=drivesdk).  The command found for evaluation need the parameter - treebank tree.txt 
The command for evaluation is:
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate -model edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz -treebank test.txt

so how can I convert my dataset in to treebank structure form. Following is code I implemented :
My program is in following form.

```
Properties props = new Properties(); props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, sentiment"); StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props); Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(text); List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class); for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) { String sentiment = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class); System.out.println(sentiment + "\t" + sentence); }
```

I need answer in J2SE form also is any way to evaluate the results in J2SE rather than command line option. please let me know if you have solution

Comment: Looks like you have two questions here. You also need to provide more information than `I need answer in J2SE form` .. what do you mean ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code there. Code in comments is very hard to read.